# No such file directory when compile solidity with node fs library

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm trying to compile solidity using `node compile.js`. I have attached the code below:

Here is my simple demo structure:

contracts

- node_modules
- compile.js
- Incrementer.sol
- package.json
- package-lock.json

Here is compile.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const path = require('path');

// Get Path and Load Contract
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'Incrementer.sol');
console.log(inboxPath) // This one provide directory to read (/Users/amstriker/Desktop/Sdax/OnePlace/contracts/Incrementer.sol'
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8'); // still getting stuck on this

// Compile Contract
const input = {
   language: 'Solidity',
   sources: {
      'Incrementer.sol': {
         content: source,
      },
   },
   settings: {
      outputSelection: {
         '*': {
            '*': ['*'],
         },
      },
   },
};
const tempFile = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
const contractFile = tempFile.contracts['Incrementer.sol']['Incrementer'];

// Export Contract Data
module.exports = contractFile;
```

Incrementer.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Incrementer {
    uint256 public number;

    constructor(uint256 _initialNumber) {
        number = _initialNumber;
    }

    function increment(uint256 _value) public {
        number = number + _value;
    }

    function reset() public {
        number = 0;
    }
}
```

Packages.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "solc": "^0.8.0",
    "web3": "^1.5.3"
  }
}
```

I have been tried many different approach but still getting errors:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:314
throw err;
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 

'/Users/amstriker/Desktop/Sdax/OnePlace/contracts/Incrementer.sol'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amstriker/Desktop/Sdax/OnePlace/contracts/compile.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/steven/Desktop/Sdax/OnePlace/contracts/get.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/amstriker/Desktop/Sdax/OnePlace/contracts/Incrementer.sol'
}
```

Any helps would be appreciated!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It failed because of space solidity filename( `Incrementer.sol`). It is working fine after i changed from  `Incrementer.sol` to `Incrementer.sol`.